# Getting unique elements of List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set, hashset

all I have list containing Duplicate values I want somehow to get only Unique values from it and store it another list or set.So that I can perform some operation on it.
My code:

```
{
        List<Integer[]> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
          list1.add(new Integer[] { 1,10 });
            list1.add(new Integer[] { 1,10 });
            list1.add(new Integer[] { 1,10 });      
            list1.add(new Integer[] { 2,10 });
            list1.add(new Integer[] { 1,10 });
            list1.add(new Integer[] { 3,10 });

        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("I - 0 :"+list1.get(i)[0]+"\t I - 1 :"+list1.get(i)[1]+"\n");
        }

        Set<Integer[]> uniquelist = new HashSet<Integer[]>(list1);

        for(Integer[] number: uniquelist){
              System.out.println(number[0]+"\t"+number[1]);
            }
    }
```

I want the result `{1,10;2,10;3,10}` to be in separate list.When i googled I got to know for unique we should use set as in `Set<Integer[]> uniquelist = new HashSet<Integer[]>(list1);` But after doing this I dont know how to access each elements Thanks in advance

```
Output:
1   10
2   10
1   10
3   10
1   10
1   10
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+iterate+over+set+in+java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get the result you want using the normal `Set` approach. As your `List` contains `Integer[]`, and then won't be considered unique by default. All the array objects are distinct. So, your `Set` will contain the same elements as your list. However, you can define your `Custom Comparator`, and use it with a `TreeSet` constructor.

Another way of doing it can be, define a method `contains(List<Integer[]> list, Integer[] value)`, which checks whether your list contains that array. Define a list named `uniqueList`. Now, iterate over your original list, and then for each value, call `contains` method passing `uniqueList` and that `value`, as parameters.

Here's how your `contains` method would look like: -

```
public static boolean contains(List<Integer[]> list, Integer[] value) {
    for (Integer[] arr: list) {
        // We can compare two arrays using `Arrays.equals` method.
        if (Arrays.equals(arr, value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, you can see that, checking for containment is not the same as, how it would look for just `Integer`.

Now, from your `main` method, use this code: -

```
List<Integer[]> unique = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

for (Integer[] arr: list1) {
    // Use your method here, to test whether this value - `arr` 
    // is already in `unique` List or not. If not, then add it.
    if (!contains(unique, arr)) {
        unique.add(arr);
    }
}

for (Integer[] arr: unique) {
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use a `Set` implementation in this case. Use `LinkedHashSet` if you want your elements to be ordered.

You could declare a class IntegerPair to hold your pairs:

```
class IntegerPair {
  private int key;

  private int value;

  public IntegerPair(int k, int v) {
    key = k;
    value = v;
  }

  public int getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return key * value;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof IntegerPair)) {
      return false;
    }
    IntegerPair other = (IntegerPair) o;
    return key == other.key && value == other.value;
  }
}
```

Declare it this way:

```
Set<IntegerPair> set = new LinkedHashSet<IntegerPair>();
```

Instead of putting `new Integer[]` values, just do `set.add(new IntegerPair(1, 10));`

You can loop through your elements using the foreach approach:

```
for (IntegerPair value : set) {
  System.out.println(value.getKey() + "  =  " + value.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, the `Set` implementation would not work here. See the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Well, I like the idea, but it may fail, if the integer array contains more than two values.

Comment: @Dan thanks but map.put(1,2); map.put(1,10); map.put(2,2); map.put(2,10);
map.put(3,10);  give sme only 1-10,2-10,3-10 and 2-2,1-2 is missing

Comment: OK, I changed back to a Set based implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can access elements by `Iterator` or by using for each loop

```
for(Integer number: setOfNumbers){
  System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them into set using your custom comparator like following:

```
new TreeSet(list1, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
    public int compare(Integer[] one, Integer[] two) {
        int n = one.length;
        for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++) {
              int comp = one.compareTo(two);
              if (comp != 0) {
                   return comp;
              }
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Pay attention that I used `TreeSet` that can accept custom comparator. It is because you are dealing with arrays. If however you define your own class that holds 2 int values you can make it to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` that allows using any Set implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) collection in [Google-guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

**Example :**

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Integer[]> sampleTable = HashBasedTable.create();
sampleTable.put(1, 10, new Integer[] { 1,10 });
sampleTable.put(2, 10, new Integer[] { 2,10 });
sampleTable.put(1, 10, new Integer[] { 1,10 });
```

So it will overwrite the duplicate values. Finally you have only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

the `Integer[] number` in your for loop is an array. to get the values inside you have to use `number[index]` instruction. to do that you can either do a classic while or for loop using a variable as an index

```
for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++) {
...
}
```

or a foreach loop:

```
for(Integer num : number){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Set<Integer []> set = new TreeSet<Integer []>(new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
            if(o1.length == o2.length){
                for(int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++){
                    if(o1[i] != o2[i]){
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });

    set.add(new Integer[]{1,2});
    set.add(new Integer[]{1,2});
    set.add(new Integer[]{1,2});
    set.add(new Integer[]{1,3});

    int j = 0;
    for(Integer[] i: set){
        System.out.println("\nElements: "+j);
        j++;
        for(Integer k : i){
            System.out.print(k+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use `Comparator` to compare two elements of same. As we don't have comparator for Array, Set will use actual object to compare.. using comparator you will have to tell set that this two arrays are same and do not add other same array